# Error with: override public func observeValueForKeyPath

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing

I am using code that worked with Xcode 7 Beta 2. Just got Beta 3 and now I'm getting this problem that seems like an Xcode bug?

For one of my public classes...

```
override public func observeValueForKeyPath...
```

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

So I take out the "override":

```
public func observeValueForKeyPath
```

> Method conflicts with method from superclass NSObject with the same Objective-C selector

ha! I was lied to by the first error. Won't compile either way. Any help please?

Comment: This may sound rudimentary, but have you cleaned your build folder (cmd-shift-k)?

Comment: That didn't help, but matt's answer (change NSObject to String) fixed it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change `[NSObject:AnyObject]` in the declaration to `[String:AnyObject]`.

Comment: Thanks that worked, sorry for the noob question but I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: It is not obvious to find out, my code completion does not work. I wish fuzzy autocomplete and alcatraz can be used again soon. :(

Answer (score 31):

If the definition is copied from `NSKeyValueObserving.h`, your override would look like the below:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    // ...
}
```

**Note:** For methods like this one, you could usually press `Cmd+Shift+O` and go straight to *Open Quickly...* pop-up field where any definition could be copy/pasted and Xcode will search for it within the project/SDK. Watch for iOS scope in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Not making the params Optional was the culprit and your answer definitely helped.

Comment: yeah +1 for the params needing to be optional

Comment: IOS:10    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {